# Is there a way to make a progress bar like that in gmail in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to make a progress bar like that in gmail in ASP.net?

Comment: Is it possible to do it using AJAX. I want a progress bar that does the same when loading gmail inbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some ASP .NET based Progress Bar controls:

- [ASP.NET AJAX Progress Bar Control](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/05/aspnet_ajax_progress_bar_contr.html)
- [ASP .NET Progress Bar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/progressbar.aspx) (ASP .NET Control Gallery)
- [ASP .NET Static Progress Bar control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/progressbar.aspx)

JavaScript alternatives:

- [jQuery ProgressBar](http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php)
- [jQuery.UI ProgressBar Widget](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/jqueryui_progressbar_widget.html)

Comment: I need the progress bar running until all the response from server is rndered to the browser, not a static one. It should run according to the response content

Comment: It's a long running process?? Do you want to show real-time statistics??

Comment: Yes, sometimes my page loads faster and sometimes a bit slow. So I have to show the bar not in a static way ( using response to flush for a specific period ) but by calculating the time it requires for the response to finish.

Comment: you can't possible calculate the exact ETA of the page your delivering, result will be undeterministic. you can use rotating animation in a modal div though then on page load remove it

Comment: I think the above site uses window.settimeout function to display a div for a particular period of time.But I don't want this. Is there any other way of doing it??