# progress bar issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to set a progress bar on my webpage which on selection of any drive information from dropdownlist shows the used space and available space. how can i do this. could any1 send me the code

This is my aspx code.

```
<fieldset style="width:1000px"> 
            <legend> Drive Info </legend> 

       <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
        <td>
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Drive"  ></asp:Label>
       </td>
       <td>

       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"   onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
      AutoPostBack="True" Height="24px"  ondatabinding="Page_Load" ondatabound="Page_Load"  
      Width="189px" ViewStateMode="Enabled" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
      <asp:ListItem Selected="True">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>

      <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Disk Name"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>
       <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Used Space"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>

       <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Free Space"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     <td>
         <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
         <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Volume Name"></asp:Label>
     </td>

     <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="System Name"></asp:Label>
    </td>
     <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>
       <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="TotalSize"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> 

      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>



     <%--<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='10px' style="background-color:#B5CCFF" >
        <tr>
            <td height='20px' width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
 </tr>
 </table>--%>
```

Comment: plz i urgently need a solution. if any1 could help

Comment: have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Are you looking for drive information of a server disk or the client?

Comment: Have you searched anything? There are many answers related to this. This might be possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408278/progress-bar-issue

Answer (score 2):

Here you have tutorial: [How to make progress bar in ASP.NET](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/themes/progress-bar-csharp.aspx)

Comment: i have seen this link, this is nt eaxctly wat i want

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the similar question

[Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412264/progress-bar)

Well Nikita, you have to add the dropdown in the updatepanel.

```
<asp:updatepanel id="uppanel1" runat="server">
  <asp:....................>
</asp:updatepanel>
<asp:updateprogress>
   ///////////// add the progress bar here.....
</asp:updateprogress>
```

Comment: i am still not getting it. i basically want how to bind dropdownlist data with the progress bar

Comment: can you please paste some of your code .. so that i can understand in detail a little bit...

Comment: Well!! i think this is the complete progress bar as per your need. http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/05/aspnet_ajax_progress_bar_contr.html, now in this add the code to add the percentage as per you code processing is begin processed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <fieldset style="width:1000px"> 
            <legend> Drive Info </legend> 

       <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
        <td>
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Drive"  ></asp:Label>
       </td>
       <td>

       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"   onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
      AutoPostBack="True" Height="24px"  ondatabinding="Page_Load" ondatabound="Page_Load"  
      Width="189px" ViewStateMode="Enabled" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
      <asp:ListItem Selected="True">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>

      <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Disk Name"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>
       <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Used Space"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>

       <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Free Space"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     <td>
         <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
         <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Volume Name"></asp:Label>
     </td>

     <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="System Name"></asp:Label>
    </td>
     <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>
       <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="TotalSize"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> 

      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>



     <%--<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='10px' style="background-color:#B5CCFF" >
        <tr>
            <td height='20px' width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5' style="background-color:Blue"></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
            <td width='5'></td>
 </tr>
 </table>--%>
```

Comment: Well Nikita you can easily integrate the pop-up in this. here is the live example and sample code for this. And in code behind you have to code to increase the percentage in progress bar. http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=ASP.NET+AJAX+Progress+Bar+Control&Filter=All

Comment: Fine... i am some what busy now... please give me 2-3 hours, i will integrate it and post that to you.

Comment: @bhavik: u were going to post the integrated code. could u plz show me how to do it. i am really stuck

Comment: i thought you might have got so i didn't post... fine, i will post it with in couple of hours.

Comment: I will send you the project as soon as integrate that. Please sent me an email from your Id to bhavikgoyal@gmail.com